# Nivo slider resize his height at the begining

Tags: slider, nivo-slider

Please run this page with IE:

http://www.capulloscompany.com/

I'm using nivoslider, as you can see, at the begining the height of the slider resizes itself.
The height of the images is the height you see once it is resized. For an strange reason, the first image is decreasing his original height. Does anyone know what is the problem?? Ty

Comment: I don't have this issue on Chrome 28

Comment: Is just in IE that's what I said run it over IE.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I'll take a look.